# C#, SendKeys to another foreground app, ignore app keyboard

Tags: c#

I lunched some application from inside C# via Process p = Process.Start() and I installed a global key hook like this:

```
id = GlobalAddAtom("My Brilliant Appplication");
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, id, (int)MOD_SHIFT, (int)Keys.K);

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("You pressed the Windows Key and the K Key!");

                IntPtr h = IntPtr.Zero;
                h = GetForegroundWindow();
                //ShowWindowAsync(h, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED); // minimize

                SendKeys.SendWait("dir");
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
```

The problem is the receiving application will also receive my KEY combination itself.

I try to give some automatic commands to foreground "putty" and the KEY combination is (for testing) SHIFT+K. It's working, but my "putty" receives "DIR" instead of originally "dir" since the SHIFT is still pressed.

Any idea? Thanks very much in advance,

Comment: Don't use Shift+K as a hot key then. Or maybe there is a way to send *flag* keys (to example, Control) via `SendKeys`, then just override them (turn them off before sending `dir`).

Comment: Can you be little more specific please? I tried CTRL+KEY but a lot of garbage is send instead of actual string

Comment: Control will send modifier commands if you're using it in putty (assuming from what you've written). I can't find a way to actually remove the shift modifier, but perhaps you could `SendKeys.SendWait("{CAPSLOCK}dir{CAPSLOCK}");` That's my only idea besides some loop that waits for shift to be released before doing work.

Comment: Thanks all, I will just pop-up my app and use "custom commands" from there. I'd thought there must be a win hack more easily :) Thanks

Comment: Something like this would be more suited for an application like Autohotkey or some other scripting application. They have a much better hotkey interface. Just an idea in case this is something you'd want to do more of. I've used it to automate tedious testing, games, and even something simple like replacing strings as I type.

Comment: You could try sending a `WM_CHAR` message to the target window. That way it doesn't even need to be in the foreground.